# Best way to connect an arraylist item to a thread and other way around

Tags: java, android, multithreading, arraylist

I'm working on an Android app that includes an ArrayList of objects. 
Each object in the Arraylist represents a Bluetooth device that my app is connected to.

For each device in the Arraylist, a thread is running that does the Bluetooth communication. (I'm planning to put these threads in an array also).

The thing i'm struggling with is: What is the best way to connect the Arraylist-item to the thread and other way around?

Because the when something changes to the Arraylist-item, the thread has to communicate this change. And when the thread receives communication it should modify the Arraylist-item it's 'working for'.

Solutions I've been thinking of:

- I could give both thread and Arraylist-item an unique ID and iterate their array/arrylist when one needs the other. But this seems slow.
- I could add the thread object to my custom device object in the Arraylist so everything is in the same Arraylist. But this doesn't feel like something i should do. The Arraylist will be sorted often and i don't know if when sorted, all the data is relocated (=> How does this influence the thread...). Or is an Ararylist just a list off references to the objects and is it only the list that is sorted, but the objects stay put...

Both options don't seem like the best solution. Does anybody know what the best way is to do this?

I'm not really used with working with threads and Arraylists yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Or is an Ararylist just a list off references to the objects and is it only the list that is sorted, but the objects stay put...

Yes, as you guessed just references are stored. That's because in Java you can have [only references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1) to objects.

> What is the best way to connect the Arraylist-item to the thread and other way around?

You can make a `Map<Device, Thread>`, this way you can easily get the `Thread` associated with the object. For the association in the other way you should extend the `Thread` class to store a reference to the device. To be sure that the associations are correct you can create your own association class backed by a map and responsible of creating and starting the thread

```
public class Association{
   private Map<MyDevice, MyThread> map;

   public MyThread add(MyDevice device){
      MyThread t = new MyThread(device);
      map.put(device, t);
       return t;
   }

   public void stopThread(final Device d){
      final Thread t = map.get(d);
      if(t != null && t.isAlive()){
         new Thread( () -> {
            t.interrupt();
            try{ t.join(); }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){}
         }).start();

         map.remove(d);
      }
   }

   ... // Constructor, thread getter, remove logic, sorting...
}
```

Comment: "... because in Java you can have only references to objects..."  I'm not sure a Java program would be very interesting if it could not have any objects.  I think what you mean is that Java _variables_ and Java _arrays_ only hold references.

Comment: @Ilario Why should i use the map when I can also make the thread a part of the Device object? I wasn't going to do that because sorting the devices would be a lot data switching, but when it is only changing the references around, I don't see a problem, or is there?

Comment: I personally don't like circle references, that's why the map. Nothing prevents you to do that, depends on your needs and personal taste ^^
@james Yes, I meant that the variables hold just object references, unlike C++ in which you can actually pass objects by value

Comment: @Ilario Ok, thanks for the info!
One more question: When i use the mapping, I have "Thread1" and i have  "Map1" which connects "Thread1" and "Device1". What if somewhere in my program, i kill Thread1 by putting "Thread1=null". Will the thread really be destroyed? Since Map1 still holds a reference to the object that "Thread1" is. (what i read is that objects are only collected by the garbage collector when there are no references left to it) And as far as I know making a reference to an object "null" does not make all the references to the object "null"...

Comment: You don't _kill_ threads by putting the reference equal to null... threads complete their execution once they reach the end of the `run()` method, or else when they are interrupted and they reach an interruption point.
And in my proposal you have an `Association` class exactly to avoid the garbage collection problems: the only reference to the thread is kept in the private map, only the `Association` object can access it; you can define your own stop logic inside Association (I will edit the answer to show it)

Comment: Ok I see now. The thread only exists in the map. Thanks for the advice!